# In which database table are products and categories coupled

Tags: product, category, database, magento-1

Each product can be assigned to a category. I was wondering in which database table these products and categories are coupled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

product and category relation has been saved at table `catalog_category_product` and `catalog_category_product_index`.`catalog_category_product` is the main table

Comment: Is there any documenation about this? I can only find an entity relation diagram.

Comment: [Magereverse](http://www.magereverse.com)  can be helpful

Comment: If I was to upload those three tables from and existing store into a new DB with a new stand alone magento build... would i have all my products available?